# Can not download html with phantomjs

Tags: javascript, php, url, phantomjs

I have 3 different files in my project and the layout is

- phantomjs
- -->phantomjs.js
- -->phantomjs.exe
- index.php

index.php:

```
$phantom_script = dirname(__FILE__). '\phantomjs\phantomjs.js';

$response =  exec ('\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe' . $phantom_script);

echo $response;
```

phantomjs\phantomjs.js

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://www.google.com', function(status) {
   console.log(page.content);
   phantom.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your usage oh phantomjs is correct according to the documentation.
http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/content.html

php exec method returns the last line only.
Maybe that line is a white space.
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.exec.php

You shall have a seond parameter &$output, sent by reference. It is an array containing the entire output.

A problem you may face later, the content could need be to evaluated before you try to read it s DOM document content. Using for example innerHTML of HTML tag, ie: $('html').html();

If the page does not have jquery, you may include it, see this example, https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/phantomwebintro.js

Note also that google may actively desire to not let users scrap and save their search results. Not sure about that.

Comment: How would you use the second parameter.